# How to create a global model with personalized features for multi-label classification problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, linear-regression, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to predict additional recipients of a message given the content of the message (like subject and body) and the current recipients of the message.

for ex: I have 4 users in the system U1, U2, U3 and U4

I have the following messages between them

```
message-id  message-content sender  recipients
     m1          text        U1      U2,U3
     m2          text        U1      U2
     m3          text        U1      U3
     m4          text        U2      U3,U4
     m5          text        U3      U4
```

As you can see U1 only communicates (Send/Receive) with U2 and U3. Similarly, U2 communicates with U1, U3 and U4 while U3 communicates with U1, U2 and U4. Lastly U4 communicates with U2 and U3.

My goal is when a user is composing a message and already entered some content and recipients on the To line, I want to suggest other recipients the user should include in the To line. The suggestion should be relevant to the message's content and also only contain users with whom the user has communicated with previously.

So for U1 we should never recommend U4 as there is no communication between them before. Similarly, for U4 we would never suggest U1.

I'm currently thinking of solving this as a multi-label classification problem where I generate a personalized model per user using Binary Relevance method.

For U1, the data looks as follows

```
message-id  message-content U2  U3
   m1          text         1   1
   m2          text         1   0
   m3          text         0   1
```

Now, I can train a OneVsRest classifier (from scikit-learn) on this data using svm.LinearSVC (or some other classifier) to predict multi-recipients given a message. I'll use content and recipients of the message as features. This works.

The problem is this needs a personalized model per user. Given I have 10's of millions of users and each user sends/receives 1000's of messages per month and communicates with 1000's of other users overall, how can I create a single global model with personalized features for prediction?

I want to avoid creating millions of personal model per user if possible and want to train a single global model using data for all users and then do personalized predictions.

Is multi-label classification not suitable for learning a global model? Should I instead use a ranking model approach?

Please suggest how can I do this?

Comment: A multilabel classification model is appropriate. Here's some inspiration: [Towards Building Effective Email Recipient Recommendation Service](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6273570), [Recipient Recommendation in Enterprises Using Communication Graphs and Email Content](https://pure.uva.nl/ws/files/2461090/149551_sigir2014_recipientrecommendation_1_.pdf)